# Euribor 3M simulation

Tags: interest-rates, calibration, hullwhite

I am required to simulate the trajectory of the Euribor3M rate as it is crucial for determining the future cash flows of my derivative instrument. I've received guidance to employ the Hull-White model. How can I transition from the short rate to Euribor? Is it accomplished through the forward zero-coupon bond?

I am following Brigo-Mercurio, but I don't understand what is the correct way to get it, so I really need advice so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are within a EURIBOR 3M discounting framework, just use the definition of EURIBOR 3M in terms of discount factors.

$$
L\left(t, T, T + \text{3M}\right) = \frac{1}{\delta\left(T, T + \text{3M}\right)}
\left[\frac{P\left(t, T\right)}{P\left(t, T + \text{3M}\right)} - 1\right]
$$

And use the analytic formulas available in the Hull-White model for discount bonds $P \left(t, \cdot\right)$ as a function of your (simulated) short rate $r_t$.

Comment: Shouldn't be like that? $$
L\left(t, T, T + \text{3M}\right) = \frac{1}{\delta\left(T, T + \text{3M}\right)}
\left[\frac{P\left(t, T \right)}{P\left(t, T+ \text{3M}\right)} - 1\right]
$$

Comment: Correct! Modified, thanks